# Coordinate system with images on Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, plot

I saw someone doing plotting with images in C#.

So you can drag with right-click + mouse-movement and also add images to different coordinates.
I got really interested and tried to simulate this in a pictureBox with half of an success.

Does someone know if this is a nuget package control or have some ideas for librarys for doing that?

[image: Image based coordinate system]

Comment: I've never used a library, but it can be done with a [Bitmap](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/12/draw-on-a-bitmap-in-c/). This bitmap can be assigned to the [PictureBox.Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: but how could I generate the bitmap that I have like -2000 to 2000 on the x-axis and -2000 to 2000 on y-axis?

Comment: You should not use one pixel for one unit. So you could use a Bitmap of 500x500, so each pixel represents 4 units. You should learn more about vector graphics. Or use the buildin [Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/types-of-coordinate-systems) In this case the `myGraphics.ScaleTransform(4);` and `myGraphics.TranslateTransform();` would be usefull. This way you can create virtual spaces.

Comment: okay, good point. I will take a look into it. Thanks :)